# Why is $k \rightarrow A \rightarrow A / I$ and isomorphism of rings if $I \subset A$ is maximal?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a algebraically closed field, $A$ a finitely generated $k$-Algebra and $I \subset A$ a maximal ideal. Let $\varphi: k \rightarrow A$ be a ring homomorphism.
Why is this combination
$$k \rightarrow A \rightarrow A / I$$
an isomorphism?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The general case is ***not going to be true*** and here is why: Take $k = \Bbb{C}$, $A = \big(\Bbb{C}(x)\big)[y]$ and $I = (y)$ that is maximal since $\big(\Bbb{C}(x)\big)[y]/(y) \cong \Bbb{C}(x)$ is a field. But now $ \Bbb{C}(x)$ is much bigger than $\Bbb{C}$ (in fact infinite dimensional over $\Bbb{C}$) and so your compositum cannot possibly be an isomorphism.

Your result though ***is true*** in the case when $A$ is a ***finitely generated $k$ - algebra***. If $I$ is a maximal ideal then $A/I$ is a finitely generated $k$ - algebra that is a field, and hence by Zariski's lemma is a finite algebraic extension of $k$. Since $k$ is algebraically closed, $A/I = k$ and so your compositum can be viewed as an injective linear map between two $1$ - dimensional vector spaces and thus is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you! In my case $A$ is indeed a finitely generated $k$-algebra.

Comment: @Haderlump Perhaps you should specify in your question that you are after the case that $A$ is a f.g. $k$ - algebra.